# Disappear widgets without using pack or grid in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Is there a way I can make a widget invisible without the use of `.pack` or a `.grid`. I'm using `.place` to set coordinates. If any of you need an example of my code, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for `place_forget`?  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm#Tkinter.Place.place_forget-method

Comment: yes, lol. I'll go research on it. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: @mgilson: you should write your advice as an answer, since `place_forget` is the actual answer to the question.

Comment: @BryanOakley -- I suppose you're correct.  It just seemed difficult to stretch it out into a full answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for the [`place_forget`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm#Tkinter.Place.place_forget-method) method.

This isn't too different than if you were to be using the `.grid` or `.pack` geometry managers where the methods to remove a widget are `grid_forget` and `pack_forget` respectively.